# USSD setup error in mvn clean install -Pjboss

Tags: ussd, ss7

I am following http://code.google.com/p/ussdgateway/wiki/DeployUSSDGWFromTrunk link to setup USSD on my pc.
but getting build failure when try in do mvn clean install -Pjboss

plz help.

java.lang.Exception: Creation of AS failed. Other AS with name=testas already exist
ERROR org.mobicents.protocols.ss7.m3ua.impl.oam.M3UAShellExecutor  - Error while executing comand [m3ua, asp, create, testasp1, testAssoc1]
java.lang.Exception: Creation of ASP failed. Other ASP with name=testasp1 already exist

Like that so many exceptions
**IT IS SHOWING exactly LIKE THIS**--->>>>> http://markmail.org/download.xqy?id=blu6kctmlu6g6oyv&number=1

Comment: Please post your error message.

Comment: http://markmail.org/download.xqy?id=blu6kctmlu6g6oyv&number=1

Comment: IS there anybody to help!!!

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen can u pls provide me some info on this....